# bootstrap: making table readable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap to style a table and it renders with very small fonts on my device (galaxy s5). I want it to render with normal sized fonts and for the text to wrap if required. For my real use case, I must use a table.

https://jsfiddle.net/wcrrja2f/

for the full screen: 
https://jsfiddle.net/wcrrja2f/embedded/result/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="col-xs-12">
            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</td>
                <td class="col-xs-2">12</td>
                <td class="col-xs-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want to have bigger font on small devices or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the normal size of the text inside table cell.
If you want to increase the font size on all devices you can use `17px` (change it to your needs):

```
td {
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

or if you want to increase the font size **only** on small devices you can use media query to target devices with smaller resolution like `480px`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    td {
        font-size: 17px;
    }
}
```

Also if you don't want to use additional CSS styles you could wrap the text inside `<h3>` which will make it bigger.